# Server 2008 Firewall not allowing connection through

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

Running Server 2008 R2. I'm trying to get a [Zabbix](http://zabbix.com) agent working. The agent works if I turn off the firewall on the server. For obvious reasons, I don't want to leave the firewall off.

As per the Zabbix instructions, I opened inbound TCP ports 10050-10051 on the server (also tried UDP) via WF.msc. As soon as the firewall is turned on, everything stops working. I enabled the firewall log which of course is (and remains) empty. Nothing in event viewer, either.

Any ideas why WF.msc directives might not be honored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you verify that the application behavior matches the documentation: type `netstat -anb` in an elevated command-line and you'll get a list of open ports with the associated executable (if possible).

Once you have that, make sure your rules matches the actual listening pattern of your application.

An alternative would be to open the ports not based on port number but based on the executable itself. That might make it easier to manage.

Comment: I tried adding the executable but it didn't appear to work. Tried it again just now, and it seems to be OK. Another MSFT mystery solved. Thx.